# Acces violation on instance variable

Tags: delphi, interface, reference

i have two class. One abstract (XmlNodeManager) and your concrete child XmlEnpManager.
The abstract class definition is:

```
type
  TXmlNodeManager = class
    public
      constructor Create(aRoot: IXMLNode); virtual; abstract;
      function Size(): Integer;
   protected
      { sgy alias para strategy }
      sgyIterator: Integer;
      sgyAttributes: TStringList;
      sgyRoot: IXMLNode;
  end;
```

And, the subclass:

```
type
  TXmlEnpManager = class (TXmlNodeManager)
    public
      constructor Create(aRoot: IXMLNode); override;
  end;
```

The constructor is implemented in subclass, and have the next code:

```
constructor TXmlEnpManager.Create(aRoot: IXMLNode);
begin
  sgyIterator := 0;
  sgyRoot := aRoot;
  Self.GenerateAttribs;
end;
```

whereas that size() method are implemented in the father:

```
function TXmlNodeManager.Size(): Integer;
begin
  Size := sgyRoot.ChildNodes.Count;
end;
```

When i create an instance of XmlEnpManager, and pass a defined IXMLNode as param, and send Size() message. The program fails (in execution time) with acces violation on sgyRoot.ChildNodes.Count.

I do the next check:

```
function TXmlNodeManager.Size(): Integer;
begin
  if (Assigned(sgyRoot)) then
    ShowMessage('Root assigned.')
  else
    ShowMessage('Root not assigned ???');
end;
```

Show the second alert. Im newest in Delphi, and suspect that Interface reference is by value, unlike as objects. Is correct ?.
How solves this problem ? Any ideas ?.

Edit: I do down-casting. I have a variable of type XmlNodeManager, that is initilize with a subclass of XmlNodeManager. This, is correct ?. Example:

```
// aNode can be a instance of TXmlEnpManager or another subclass of TXmlNodeManager.
procedure TXmlFileManager.SetCurrentNode(aNode: TXmlNodeManager);
    begin
      // xmCurrentNode is of TXmlNodeManager type
      xmCurrentNode := aNode;
    end;
```

Comment: I'd still suggest you to do the same check in the constructor, `if Assigned(aRoot) ..`, or perhaps 'GenerateAttribs' is overwriting the interface.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz   yes, is assigned. Sorry, i dont explain whats GenerateAttribs do, this method creates a TListString, no more.

Comment: @ramiromd: show the code that is calling `TXmlEnpManager.Create()`. Given the code you have shown, the caller is likely passing a nil `IXMLNode` to `Create()`, which you should be checking for in `Size()` anyway: `if Assigned(sgyRoot) then Result := sgyRoot.ChildNodes.Count else Result := 0;`

Comment: [Debug it.](https://twitter.com/rkennedy/status/365678718993170433) Follow the data. Confirm that you call the constructor you think you're calling. Then confirm the constructor receives the interface you think it does. Finally, confirm that the object you call `Size` on is the same one you got from calling the constructor earlier. The debugger can help you with each of those steps.

Comment: If you can't debug this yourself, and it looks very simple to debug if you'd just try, then you'll need to supply an SSCCE.

Comment: SSCE = [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: Why don´t you turn the abstract constructor into a concrete one and assign the parameter to the field member? In the subclass´ constructor you should call inherited to run the ancestor´s constructor and do anything else you need.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, you should call the inherited constructor from your constructor:

```
constructor TXmlEnpManager.Create(aRoot: IXMLNode);
begin
  INHERITED Create;
  sgyIterator := 0;
  sgyRoot := aRoot;
  Self.GenerateAttribs;
end;
```

Comment: The inherited constructor is abstract, and so the compiler will simply ignore the code that you added. The compiler will emit the same object code as for the source in the question.

Comment: Worse, it would cause an abstract error, if it would compile that is (inherited constructor signature is different).

Comment: You are mistaken. The inherited constructor is abstract, so neglecting to call it is obviously not the reason for the problem. However, the lack of inherited call does point to the class's poor design. There's probably no reason for the constructor to be virtual, let alone abstract. A class should always be responsible for initializing its own fields, so the base class should be what assigns `sgyRoot`, `sgyIterator`, and `sgyAttributes`. If anything should be abstract, it's `GenerateAttribs`, which should fill, but not assign, `sgyAttributes`. Nonetheless, this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Are you sure? I'm aware that it won't call the direct parent's constructor (it doesn't have a parameterless constructor), but I would expect it to call TObject.Create and thus clear all memory of the object to zero.

Comment: Actually, it won't even compile (Missing parameter). And if changed to a simple INHERITED; (no name), the line is ignored. Whereas, if changed to INHERITED Create(aRoot); it'll throw an Abstract Exception (as expected).

Comment: TObject.Create does nothing. It's NewInstance the initializes the object to zero. Since you know that this answer is wrong, I cannot understand why you don't remove it. It's not helpful to the community to leave inaccurate answers.